# How to get and set property of an object which might be property of another object?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have an object called `myConstraint` which **might** have a property called `Parameter`.

The `Parameter` is an object that has the `Name` property which is of type string.

I want to check `Constraint` and if it has the property `Parameter` get the string `Parameter.Name` and if it is equal to "Length" Set the value of `Constraint.Parameter` to `myLengthParameter`.

I cannot use Constraint.Parameter since the compiler does not know if the object has property Parameter until program is run. I tried to use reflection but I could not figure this out. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Cast the `object` to your class, example `((Constraint)myConstraint).Parameter`

Comment: what do you mean *Might Have*? why not just put it there, if you don't need `Parameter`, let it be `null`?

Comment: @kienct89: it is not my code, I am just using this class.

Comment: @j3soon: `myConstraint` is object of an abstract class which might be any inherited subclass of `Constraint`. Some of the inherited classes have property `Parameter`. So `((Constraint)myConstraint).Parameter` wouldn't work.

Comment: I think reflection can help solve this. Something like: `var property = constraint.GetType().GetProperty("Parameter");` but I don't know how to get `Parameter.Name` uing reflection.

Comment: @Saeid can you modify the classes?

Comment: @Alberto: Thanks, your answer solved the problem, so I don't have to modify classes.

Comment: @Saied you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you can use reflection to do that.

Since **constraint** variable can have any value, so you can do something like that.

```
var property = constraint.GetType().GetProperty("Parameter"); 

if (property != null)
{
    var parameter = property.GetValue(constraint);
    if (parameter != null)
    {
        var parameterName = parameter.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(parameter).ToString();
        if (parameterName == "Length")
        {
            property.SetValue(constraint, myLengthParameter);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the instance type using [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx), then cast the object to the `Constraint` type. (refer to J3soon's comment)

```
if (myConstraint is Constraint)
{
   // cast and perform your operations here
}
```

Comment: There are numerous possibilities. This wouldn't work. I think using Reflection should help. Please see my comments.